# How to correctly configure systemd-networkd-wait-online.service to exit when an interface reaches a certain operational state?

Tags: networking, systemd, systemctl, systemd-networkd

I am trying to optimise my boot time for systemd, which currently stands at over 2 minutes. `systemd-analyze` shows the culprit for this to be `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`, which - according to the documentation - has a timeout of 2 minutes by default.

I need to ensure that `enp1s0` has a routable state before continuing, so to prevent this from hanging, I have tried to do this based on the documentation [here](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.8.en.html) with the following:

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i enp1s0:routable
```

I expect this to successfully exit the `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` when the operational state of `enp1s0` is routable, however it does not, and instead hangs until the timeout.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here? For reference, this is the output of the `networkctl` command:

```
IDX LINK            TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP
  1 lo              loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eth0            ether    no-carrier  configuring
  3 enp1s0          ether    routable    configuring
```